# Is there a way to clear saved wireless connection settings in XP at logoff

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, credentials

We have a load of old stand alone Windows XP netbooks that are loaned out to staff on a daily basis.
Different staff use the machines at different times depending on their needs.
We have 2 different wireless networks at the university, each one requires authenticated login using the users university domain username and password. 
Whenever a user logs on to the Stand Alone wireless laptops that we provide and connect to the wireless their settings seem to be saved on the laptop. (This is bad as any further use of the laptop on the wireless network looks like it comes from them, I would like to prevent this being the case) the check box to remember my username and password is not checked.
I know I can simply remove the Wireless networks from the list of saved networks but they require configuration in order for the users to be able to connect in the first place. See [Here](http://www.uclan.ac.uk/students/it/files/eduroam_windows_xp.docx)
My perfect scenario would be that the credentials are stored until logout at which point the users details would be cleared.

Also:
If they change their password then that laptop cannot connect to the network anymore as their Username is stored on the laptop and is greyed out so it can't be changed, where are these setting stored so I can clear them.

Comment: dunno about clearing after every logoff. But they're stored/can be cleared here, if you do ctrl panel..network connections..right click the wireless network connection then properties..wireless networks. Then delete all the wireless networks listed.

Comment: @barlop - I mention in the question that the networks need a sepcial configuration and so cannot be simply deleted... If only it was that simple :-)

Comment: I once used netswitcher which let me save LAN profiles, the wireless one seemed to be nulled out. I don't know if that's 'cos I was meant to enable or disable WZC or if the free version doesn't offer it.. and that's probably not really related to logout.. though may help a bit

Comment: btw, your profile picture looks like you're resting on a man's shoulder, it's a bit disturbing.

Comment: @barlop - Never thought of it looking like that. It's a reasonably attractive blonde thankfully - http://tinyurl.com/3dllxc4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PEAP credentials are stored in the registry so if you just clear out the key (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\EAPOL\UserEapInfo) at log in it should do the trick whilst leaving the actual connection info alone.

The following Powershell SCript running at logon works perfectly:

```
Remove-item -path registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\EAPOL\UserEapInfo -recurse
Restart-Service WZCSVC
```

It leaves the settings intact but clears out the users details.
The restart of the wireless service only works if Windows is managing your wireless settings and this drops the connection and restarts it searching for connections with no stored credentials (otherwise it holds onto the connection with the old credentials even though they aren't stored)